# Not able to get all subclasses from Protégé query

Tags: owl, protege, rdfs

I'm trying to get all classes information with a query like this: `tire that HasWidth some Width125`. What I expect to have is the list of all classes that have or could have the indicated width.

That's my Ontology view:
[image]

This is my custom Model for a tire called AS7

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="#AS7">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Avon AS7</rdfs:label>
      <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="https://spec.edmcouncil.org/auto/ontology/VC/VehicleParts/PneumaticTire"/>
   <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
          <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#HasWidth"/>
          <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Width"/>
      </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>
```

That is my Width class

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="#Width">
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Width</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="https://spec.edmcouncil.org/auto/ontology/VC/VehicleParts/Tire"/>
</owl:Class>
```

And here an example of subclass

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="#Width125">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Width"/>
    <rdfs:comment>Width 125.</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:isDefinedBy rdf:resource=""/>
    <rdfs:label>Width 125</rdfs:label>
</owl:Class>
```

Is my restriction/DL quey incorrect or may I miss something?

Comment: which class do you expect to be returned? I mean, you're querying for all subclasses of tires that have the specific width 125 - and the query aka inference is for all that definetely fullfil this restriction. When you say `AS7` has just "some" width, this clearly doesn't match your required witdh of 125.

Comment: by the way, I don't get why one would make `Width` a subclass of `Tire` - ontologically, I'd say this sounds "wrong" - but that's just my opinion

Comment: The width for a tire could be multiple value, for example a tire X could have more width size (125, 135, 145 ...).
For my query, what I want is that if I'm searching for a tire width 'someSize', I want to have as result all tires model classes that have that size

Comment: your query is `tire that HasWidth some Width125`, i.e. all subclasses of that, right? So, it will return only those classes which are at least the same of even more specific. Maybe I'm missing something, but why would you expect to get `AS7` as a result? That class only states to have "some" width, but it's not defined that the width is 125 or that any of it's widths is 125

Comment: How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it. The issue was on my restriction that needs to be a collections with the property intersectionOf.
The code looks like this:

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="#AllWidth">
<rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Width"/>
<owl:equivalentClass>
    <owl:Class>
        <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
            <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#HasWidth"/>
                <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Width125"/>
            </owl:Restriction>
           ...
        </owl:intersectionOf>
    </owl:Class>
</owl:equivalentClass>
</owl:Class>
```

And in the property

```
<rdfs:subClassOf>
    <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#HasWidth"/>
        <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="#AllWidth"/>
    </owl:Restriction>
</rdfs:subClassOf>
```